# SiteMap for the search engines

Tags: asp.net, sitemap, handlers

I have to make an api call and get the response. This response contains more than 4000 urls.
I have to list all these urls in the sitemap for the search engines to crawl easily. I have to write a handler for doing this task. Can someone suggest me an example for doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you are talking about a [sitemap in XML format](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html), but you didn't specify what the source is besides that you are to do an API call. However, the 3rd or so result from a Google search on "asp.net google sitemap" should give you a perfect starting point:

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/94/Create-a-Google-Site-Map-with-ASP.NET

I would suggest creating an ASHX handler (File -> New -> Generic Handler in Visual Studio) instead of a page like they do in the example.

Upload the handler to the website and add the sitemap to e.g. Google by using their Webmaster Tools.

Comment: if I have many links in the sitemap, can i specify <changefreq>daily</changefreq> and <priority>0.8</priority> once for all of them. or do i have to specify individually for every link

Comment: The priority of an URL is relative to other URLs on your site and the default value is 0.5. So just adjust the priority for the <url>s that should differ from the default and you should be able to skip setting it for the rest. I don't think you can set a default changefreq to use between URLs.

Comment: I have generated a sitemap xml with the help of a handler. this sitemap will be updated on a daily basis. Where should be the of this xml in my project? How do I confirm if the search engines actually  crawled the links in the sitemap xml?

Answer (score 0):

A quick search on Google resulted in this link:

[XML sitemap with ASP.NET](http://joelabrahamsson.com/entry/xml-sitemap-with-aspnet)

Which should get you most of the way with the handler and composing the XML.